# understanding jQuery syntax ? :

Tags: javascript, jquery, scripting

I am trying to understand what the ? and the : are doing in this code, I see it a lot in code but I never can understand what exactly it is doing?

Could someone please point me in the right direction, this bit of code is from the jQuery validate() DOCS

```
$(".selector").validate({
  invalidHandler: function(event, validator) {
    // 'this' refers to the form
    var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
    if (errors) {
      var message = errors == 1
        ? 'You missed 1 field. It has been highlighted'
        : 'You missed ' + errors + ' fields. They have been highlighted';
      $("div.error span").html(message);
      $("div.error").show();
    } else {
      $("div.error").hide();
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ? : isn't jquery, just vanilla javascript. It's called conditional (ternary) operator which can be used as shorthand for the standard if/else statement: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Conditional_%28ternary%29_operator

Basically it says

```
val = (boolean expression)? (val if boolean is true) : (val if boolean is false)
```

So in your case it's saying that `message` equals `'You missed 1 field. It has been highlighted'` if `errors == 1` is true, otherwise `message` equals `'You missed ' + errors + ' fields. They have been highlighted'`.

Comment: Okay so it basically is an alternative way of doing a check? similiar to if/else statements, my next question would be, why would you use this over a if/else statement?

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly it. You use it as a more shorthand way of assigning a value to a variable based on the if else condition.

Answer (score 2):

That is conditional (ternary) operator which is a shortcut for the standard if/else statement.
Here is an example to demonstrate:

```
var grade = 85;
console.log("You " + (grade > 50 ? "passed!" : "failed!"));

//Output: You passed!

/* The above statement is same as saying:
if(grade > 50){
    console.log("You " + "passed!");  //or simply "You passed!"
}
else{
    console.log("You " + "failed!"); 
}
*/
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var errors = 1; 
// define `message` 
// if `errors == 1`
var message = errors == 1 
        // `errors == 1`
        ? 'You missed 1 field. It has been highlighted' 
         // `errors != 1`
        : 'You missed ' + errors + ' fields. They have been highlighted';
console.log(message)
```

Answer (score 2):

[Conditional (ternary) Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

The first part before the question mark is the expression you're trying to evaluate.  The second part after the question mark and before the colon is the true-clause.  The third part after the colon is the false-clause.